# Is it possible to disable Xcode's calling home connections?

Tags: xcode

Every few minutes Xcode creates a https connection to developer.apple.com, also the build files connect sometime to this address during debugging.

Is it possible to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *XCode -> Preferences* and uncheck this checkbox, then your XCode will not go to check and download for updates automatically. Similarly uncheck under "Documentation" tab.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. Xcode still connects to "developerns.apple.com" Ports: 49800 - 49814 during startup.

Comment: have you tried by unchecking both the checkbox under components and documentation?

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked this.